# cocos creator with socket.io script

Tags: cocoscreator

I am trying to add the socket.io script to cocos creator.

and follow the example from http://www.cocoachina.com/bbs/read.php?tid-458031.html
It works find on the browser.

When i deploy to iOS device, having the following error.

Cocos2d-JS v3.9
Evaluating src/project.js failed (evaluatedOK == JS_FALSE)
/Users/liuhui/Desktop/jsb-default/src/project.js:2:ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Anyone can help? thank you

Answer (score 2):

yep  i am the author of that page.  i remember that socketIO  is still not support in ios.